# Node-red page will not load

Tags: node-red

I am working on a project using data from an OPC-UA connection (monitoring milling machines) to populate a dashboard. I successfully created a dashboard tab for one of the machines and had the data logging to an `influx db`.

This is all running on a desktop in my office. 
When I got home from work, I decided to work on it some more, so I connected to the corporate VPN using my laptop, and instead of navigating to `localhost:1880`, I went to `[desktop ip address]:1880` and I was able to continue my work.

I successfully created and deployed additional flows for 5 more machines, and I am able to view them on `[desktop ip]:1880/ui`.

The problem is, when I returned to my office today and I try to open node-red directly on the desktop using `localhost:1880`, **it will not load**. It only loads the Node-Red logo (header) and the sidebar, but no nodes in the palette. It shows the "loading" gif but that is all. It also does not show my flows. I can go to `localhost:1880/u` and see the dashboard, but I cannot do any work in node-red, either editing or creating flows with an empty palette.

I have tried rebooting, reinstalling node-red and node.js, and rebuilding (npm rebuild) to no avail.

What am I missing? Can someone please help me get node-red working again?
Thanks.

Comment: First questions are always: what versions of node-red, npm, nodejs? Then, show us the node-red console logs that appear at startup. Finally, use F12 to open the dev console and check for javascript exceptions in the console...

Comment: And what new nodes did you install?

Answer (score 0):

So, I updated my Chrome and it all works fine now. Not sure why it was working before then suddenly stopped. All good now. Thanks for the responses.